# how do I use masstransit with messgedata registering classes cleanly

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit

I am using `MassTransit` to route messages across an Azure Service bus
I am attempting to use `MessageData` (Azure Blobs)

I have a 'core' library that creates the Bus, inside of which, it has code that sets up the endpoints.

I have a library called `messages` that defines the messages that get past (used by both sender and consumer)

I have a 'consumer' who needs to get the messages.

I've seen people tell me that I simply need to add something like this:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("my_queue", e =>
{
    e.UseMessageData<BigMessage>(messageDataRepository);
}
```

To add "BigMessage" as a Message type that can receive large data fields from the MessageData blobs.

The problem is, that if I was going to do that, I'd have to register each of the messages in my 'core' code.  This would put a reference from core>messages, and would create a class that violates the open/closed principal.  (As well as just smelling really bad)

My best guess so far is to hang on to the 'e' var above and make it public, and then use it from the init code in the consumer to register the additional classes.

OR I could create a Attribute that I could put on each of the messages and scan for all classes with that attribute and register each of them.  That seems like a lot of work.

OR just bite the bullet and add a reference from core> messages and put the code in the bus constructor and change it every time a new message uses MessageData

Other ideas?

Comment: What class violates open/closed principle in this case?

Comment: In order to extend the system to handle another class, you not only have to add the new class, but also have to go back to whatever class registers the classes and add another registration.  Thus, that class is not open for extension, or closed for modifications.  I.E. Extensions are done by editing the class and adding another line.  (Also, removing a class requires the same kind of change)

Comment: Have you watched Greg Young's "8 lines of code"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you’d like to send and consume different type messages with large payload (stored in external storage), you could try to define/include a property that indicates the type of message in BigMessage class, and then you could get the resulting content and message type from the message properties inside the consumer.

**Sending a Big Message**

```
messagestype1 mes = new messagestype1()
{ 
    //contents
};
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages1);
var message = new BigMessage
{
    messagetype = "messagestype1",
    BigPayload = await _repository.PutString(data)
};
```

**Consuming the message inside a consumer**

```
public class BigMessageConsumer : IConsumer<BigMessage>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<BigMessage> context)
    {
        var mestype = await context.Message.messagetype.Value;
        var bigPayload = await context.Message.BigPayload.Value;

        // Do something with the big payload...
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct in that this is how you send/get your messages - however, the piece missing on the consuming of it is the part that I'm referring to.  Specifically, setting up the saving the payload to an Azure Blob - each of the message types need to be registered - unless you are suggesting on having a single message and putting everything (all fields) into the blob - that kind of kills the beauty of sending messages by type, and also overloads a single message handler with 100% of the messages of any type - leaving it to sort things out.